# SELECT datetime equals today in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, pdo

I want to select everything where `datetime` field in MySQL equals today.

So the datetime field is like this: `2017-03-22 10:11:45`

here is what I have:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM list WHERE date_and_time = :date_and_time");
$stmt->bindParam(':date_and_time', $today???);
$stmt->execute();
```

how can i select the rows in my table where date_and_time equals today?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just looking for today, you don't need to pass anything in. Just take advantage of MySQL's built-in functions:

```
$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM list WHERE DATE(date_and_time) = CURDATE()");
```

This will format your date_and_time field to be in a Y-m-d format, and compare it to the current date.

Comment: cool, that worked. but how about yesterday, or 2 days ago, or 3 days ago?

Comment: If you need to pass in a date, you can replace CURDATE() with your bound parameter and just pass in a Y-m-d format. Or if it's going to be a static length, you can change CURDATE() to `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)`

Comment: perfect thanks! im going to accept this answer in 5 minutes